# Stored procedure that creates a user profile and look up if value exist in other tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that creates a user profile, my form has the following fields:

```
FirstName,
LastName.
EmailAddress,
ZipCode,
Password
```

The zip code is a FK in my UserProfile of type smallint the value may or may not already exist in a table called `Location`:

```
LocationId bigInt (identity index)
ZipCode smallint
```

Is there a way from within my stored procedure to query that table, if the item exist use the PK of that entry in my stored procedure ?

This is my stored procedure so far

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_InsertInitialProfile]

@FirstName          NVARCHAR(1000),
@LastName           NVARCHAR(1000),
@EmailAddress       NVARCHAR(1000),
@ZipCode            SMALLINT,
@Password           NVARCHAR(1000)

AS

IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UserProfile WHERE EmailAddress =@EmailAddress) = 1
BEGIN
    RETURN -1 
END ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO UserProfile(FirstName,LastName,EmailAddress,Password)
    VALUES(@FirstName,@LastName,@EmailAddress,@Password)

    RETURN  Cast(@@IDENTITY as INT)
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do SP like this:

```
           CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_InsertInitialProfile]

            @FirstName          NVARCHAR(1000), 
            @LastName           NVARCHAR(1000), 
            @EmailAddress       NVARCHAR(1000), 
            @ZipCode            SMALLINT, 
            @Password           NVARCHAR(1000)  

            AS 

             varCountNbr number;

            BEGIN

               SELECT COUNT(1) INTO varCountNbr
               FROM 
                  Location
               WHERE 
                 ZipCode=@ZipCode;

               IF  varCountNbr = 0
                     INSERT @ZipCode INTO Location TABLE;
              -- You have to commit here, in order to have the PK value exists.
                     COMMIT;

               INSERT INTO USERPROFILE TABLE;

               COMMIT;


            END;
```

Comment: I am looking to query the Location table, not trying to figure out if a user already registered with this email

Comment: Then just query your location table in your SP first, to get count result, then you can do insert or not insert based on the returned count number.

Comment: I am looking for the PK if the item exists in the other table, if it's not than I have to add it to that table get the PK and use that for the SP Insert on the UserProfile

Comment: If zipcode does  not exist in the location table, then add the zip code into your location table to make sure that you will have this zip code as PK value for your userprofile table.Then add your user profile info into your userprofile table.

Comment: Create pk on location.zipcode, create fk on userProfile.zipcode.If zipcode exists on location table, then you can just insert user info into userProfile table.

Comment: I have that already, can you post a SP that actually does this ? look up if a zip code exists if it does get it's PK and set it to the userprofile FK?

Comment: Yes. my sp first will check if the zipcode exists in location table, if exists then insert user info,if not exists,then first insert zipcode info into location  table, and then insert user info into userprofile table.

Comment: (>>look up if a zip code exists if it does get it's PK and set it to the userprofile FK? ) You should set PK and Fk during table creation, not within your SP.And location table should be the PK, and userProfile should be the FK.